# Accessing JMX in production via SSH tunnel using JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jmx, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to automate a step of doing some things with JMX.

It works for development environment. but when it comes to Production which is protected behind firewall, i need to make a SSH tunnel and then only i can access the JMX console.

Earlier, i used putty or ssh to create tunnel and run my java program locally. Since we used 1-2 host, it was easier. now it became upto 10 host. now that i dont want to create tunnel every time and disconnect and run the program.

what i wanted to do is, automatically create SSH tunnel using JSch and connect JMX with the java program. i tried to do this but its not working.

I am getting 
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Runtime.exec()` to start ssh? Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[][] data = new String[][]{new String[]{"user@server1", "2000:server1:30"},
          new String[]{"user2@server4", "2000:server4:30"}};
  Process[] processes = new Process[data.length];
  for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    processes[i] = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh", data[i][0], "-L", data[i][1], "-N");
  }
  //do something else, for example, wait for user interaction here
  for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    processes[i].destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: Then i would be able to tunnel to only one box. i want to kickstart multiple tunnels parallely.

Comment: Runtime.exec is system wide. even if you execute one thread per server, i am not sure.

Comment: I've just realized that you can just create ssh `Process` es in a loop (`Runtime.exec()` returns immediately after starting the program), wait for the user to press enter or for some function to complete and then kill all those processes in a loop.